# How to start a process when application run?

Tags: vb.net, process

I want to add a process to my application, the process should be started to listen some events when the application run. I searched in Internet, and I didn't find answers...

Some people said that could use "Application.Run", but I didn't find this function in VB.NET project. Did I miss it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) static method, under System.Diagnostics namespace.
 You should be able to just write the path to the file and it should start it.